# How do i remove the very first white space from my text file in Python?

Tags: python

```
with open ('Exporting_data.txt', 'w+') as fp:


fp.write(data_Str)
fp.write('\n'+ labels_Str)

fin = open("Exporting_data.txt", "rt")
fout = open("Exporting_data_new.txt", "wt")

for line in fin:
fout.write(line.replace('preds', ''))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

I did this to remove the very first word of my text file (preds) but now it leaves a white space that I don't know how to remove. The text file now looks like that.

```
 B-Product B-Product B-Product B-Product
```

from originally,

```
preds   B-Product B-Product B-Product B-Product
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lstrip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_lstrip.asp) to get rid of the leading whitespace:

```py
fout.write(line.replace('preds', '').lstrip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.lstrip()`+fix indentation+use `with`:

```
with open ('Exporting_data.txt', 'w+') as fp:
    fp.write(data_Str)
    fp.write('\n'+ labels_Str)

with open("Exporting_data.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("Exporting_data_new.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('preds', '').lstrip())
```